# How can I get all the vouchers

Tags: django, django-oscar

I'm using django-oscar's model.

There is a need that when a user click "all my voucher",he  want to get all the voucher he has.

However, I can only find link between voucher and user in table 'basket ' and table 'voucher application'.And voucher application is for vouchers in an order,basket if for voucher in a basket.

I just want to easily get all the vouchers but 'voucher' table doesn't link to 'login user' table, how to solve it ???

Comment: Could you show your models? It'll be easier to help :-)

Comment: A voucher is applied to a basket, not to a user. Can you clarify what you mean by "all my voucher" for a user? If you want a list of all the vouchers that the user has consumed, you will have to query this through all the baskets they have created.

Comment: i want to know all the voucher the user has consumed, not consumed(Open), and Suspended.Not only he used in basket @solarissmoke.

Answer (score 1):

For consumed vouchers, you can query the `VoucherApplication` model:

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_model

VoucherApplication = get_model('voucher', 'VoucherApplication')

consumed_by_user = VoucherApplication.objects.filter(user=your_user)
```

As for the rest of your query regarding "not consumed and suspended" offers, I don't think this is possible. As noted in the comments to your question, a voucher is not associated directly with a user. If you create a voucher, that can be used by anyone that you give the voucher code to. Therefore there is no concept of a user having an unconsumed voucher.

Comment: I think i misunderstand the meaning of voucher……for example, I' m a user of amazon,it give me some coupon to use, each coupon with a end datetime,so I can look up the coupon's status,it is open or suspended or else.How to implement this??

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you mean. What you're describing sounds to me just like a voucher. If you want to issue vouchers to specific users you can do that, but you will need your own logic to keep track of who it's issued to because Oscar itself doesn't do that.

Comment: thank you.I made a m2m table between voucher and user.